# Why are NSString encoding constants implemented as variables instead of enum?

Tags: swift, nsstring, swift2

Why are encoding constants implemented as read-only variable instead of enum in Foundation?

```
public var NSUTF32StringEncoding: UInt { get }

public var NSUTF8StringEncoding: UInt { get }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://nshipster.com/rawoptionsettype points out that (normally) the conversion of `NSENUM` annotated C `enums` is in fact into a Swift `enum`. I would surmise that the ugly conversion in this case is due to the failure to adhere to the prefix naming convention. Had it been `NSStringEncodingUTF8`, etc., Apple probably would have made the Swift header to follow in Mattt's pattern. Given how old these constants are, they probably predate such conventions.

In particular, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html states:

> Enumerations
>
> By default, Swift imports enumerations by truncating enumeration value
>   name prefixes.

Since the prefix convention isn't followed, had they simply imported the Objective C header directly, they would have ended up with monstrosities like `NSStringEncoding.NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding` and they must have judged that it's better to have a tailor-made Swift header instead.

Answer (score 0):

The interface has nothing to do with the implementation. For example, the following protocol

```
protocol P {
    var value : Int { get }
}
```

can be implemented like this:

```
struct S : P {
    let value = 0
}
```

because the only requirement for the property is to be gettable, which it is.

I however don't know why it's not an enum, but I highly suspect it's because of some ancient Objective-C thing.

EDIT: Maybe it's because of all the methods that take an argument `UInt` as the encoding, because with an enum this would be `NSEncoding.Unicode.rawValue` which would enrage all Objective-C people.